# How to enable/disable a serial port?

Tags: linux, tty, serial-port

I need to disable and then enable a serial port for testing purposes on a Java program.

Since the `man` page of `setserial` is stating: "*Using UART type none will disable the port.*", I use `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS4 uart none` to disable the port. This successfully disables the serial port. To enable the serial port again, I use `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS4 -a autoconfig` and the port is up as expected.

After I've disabled the port, I do try to open the port using the [Java gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier](http://www.docjava.com/book/cgij/jdoc/gnu/io/CommPortIdentifier.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function. When I try to enable the port after the executing the `gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier` function, I get this output:

```
$ sudo setserial /dev/ttyS4 -a autoconfig
Cannot autoconfigure port: Device or resource busy
```

How can I work around this problem? Is there a better way to enable/disable the serial port? Or can I clear the list of requests made to the port?

I obviously can't just kill the process, since my test is running in it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Java gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier will have bigger problems if you delete /dev/ttySx aftes disabling the serial port.

When yoou need to enable it again you must first create the node with MAKEDEV script or mknod command. [Here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.8) is some info about creating serial devices.

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach... I need to emulate a situation where "the cable connecting in the port has fallen", and deleting the port wouldn't be the same, would it?

Comment: Always glad to learn new info. Well, disabling a port is not the best approach also. Why don't you just unplug the cable and see what is happening?

Comment: Because it's supposed to be an automated test. And I did said what I was trying to do at the beginning of the question :)

Comment: For me disabled port is _much_ different from enabled, but not connected port. I've worked with serial ports under Windows and there disabled port is something you cannot use; enabled port with broken link is something you can open from the app and can send data, and can wait forever for answer (forever = timeout in my case). If you want to do automated test better think about hardware disabling/enabling e.g. to connect 2 serial ports through 3wired cable, put a relay on TX wire and disable and enable it programmatically, through timer or by any other way.

Comment: I thought that a disabled port was the closest I could get from an unconnected one, thanks for the info. Anyway, the hardware option you described is not available to me, do you see any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, build a retranslator. A simple program that listens to ttyS0 and transmit everything to ttyS1 and back. And your connection will be A-B=C-D, where B and C is the retranslator and A and D is the tested software/hardware. And periodically stop retransmitting - that is the 'cable' problem. This can be done on one pc with 4 serial ports or 2 pcs.

Comment: I've got your idea, but I don't know how to implement it. Give me a few days and I will update my question (or post an answer) with your sugestion. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to delete `/var/lock/LCK..ttyS4`, using `rm`. As I understand, you need to unlock the device in a such way.